# Flutter can not connect to the docker localhost parse-server

Tags: flutter, docker, docker-compose, parse-platform

I am trying to run a parse-server and parse-dashboard via the following docker-compose.yml

**docker-compose:**

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  database:
    image: mongo:5.0
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
    volumes:
      - data_volume:/data/mongodb

  server:
    restart: always
    image: parseplatform/parse-server:4.10.4
    ports:
      - 1337:1337
    environment:
      - PARSE_SERVER_APPLICATION_ID=COOK_APP
      - PARSE_SERVER_MASTER_KEY=MASTER_KEY_1
      - PARSE_SERVER_CLIENT_KEY=CLIENT_KEY_1
      - PARSE_SERVER_DATABASE_URI=mongodb://admin:admin@mongo/parse_server?authSource=admin
      - PARSE_ENABLE_CLOUD_CODE=yes
    links:
      - database:mongo
    volumes:
      - data_volume:/data/server
      - ./../lib/core/database/parse_server/cloud:/parse-server/cloud

  dashboard:
    image: parseplatform/parse-dashboard:4.0.0
    ports:
      - "4040:4040"
    depends_on:
      - server
    restart: always
    environment:
      - PARSE_DASHBOARD_APP_ID=COOK_APP
      - PARSE_DASHBOARD_MASTER_KEY=MASTER_KEY_1
      - PARSE_DASHBOARD_USER_ID=admin
      - PARSE_DASHBOARD_USER_PASSWORD=admin
      - PARSE_DASHBOARD_ALLOW_INSECURE_HTTP=true
      - PARSE_DASHBOARD_SERVER_URL=http://localhost:1337/parse
    volumes:
      - data_volume:/data/dashboard

volumes:
  data_volume:
    driver: local
```

After the container is running via `docker-compose up` I am trying to connect to it using Flutter and write a new class to my server:

**Flutter code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:parse_server_sdk_flutter/parse_server_sdk.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  const keyApplicationId = 'COOK_APP';
  const keyClientKey = 'CLIENT_KEY_1';
  const keyParseServerUrl = 'http://localhost:1337/parse';

  var res = await Parse().initialize(keyApplicationId, keyParseServerUrl,
      clientKey: keyClientKey, autoSendSessionId: true);
     
  var connRes = await res.healthCheck();
  var s = connRes.error?.message ?? "";
  print("ERROR:" + s);

  var firstObject = ParseObject('FirstClass')
    ..set(
        'message', 'Hey ! First message from Flutter. Parse is now connected');
  await firstObject.save();

  print('done');

}
```

My error message:

```
SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = localhost, port = 35262
```

But for some unknown reason, I can not connect to my local server even if I can access with no problem my dashboard.

Comment: What is the error message? Where are you running the flutter app?

Comment: I've updated my code with this line `var s = connRes.error?.message ?? "";
  print("ERROR:" + s);` and my error message is `SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = localhost, port = 35262`

Comment: @DaviMacêdo could you help me with any advice if you know please :)

Comment: Your parse server port is 1337 and the error is showing 35262. How are you initializing the SDK? Also, where are you running the app?

Comment: Regarding the SDK I'm just running `docker-compose up` on that file that docker-compose.yml. Regarding the app, I'm running it using flatter and that main file with an android emulator.

Comment: So the problem is probably happening because you are running the app on emulator and you are initializing the sdk with localhost as the parse server address. In the context of the emulator, localhost is the emulator itself, but you want it actually to resolve to the hosting machine. Try to use 10.0.2.2 instead of localhost on emulator. This article may be helpful to you: https://medium.com/@podcoder/connecting-flutter-application-to-localhost-a1022df63130

Answer (score 0):

Your application running on the mobile device/emulator will treat localhost as own machine. In order to access the parse server running on your host machine (docker image exposing 0.0.0.0 global) you need to specify the host IP address.

Just replace `const keyParseServerUrl = 'http://localhost:1337/parse';` with `const keyParseServerUrl = 'http://YOUR_HOST_IP_ADDRESS:1337/parse';` provided in the docker parse server `0.0.0.0` should be exposed.